# Note $\frac {788\cdot\cdot\cdot 7}{239}$

Tags: number-theory

$\frac {7887}{239}=33$

$\frac {78888888887}{239}=330079033$

$\frac {788888888888888887}{239}=3300790330079033$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\frac {71\cdot 10^n-17}{9}$ is so divisible by $239$ when n=3, 10, 17, 24,...?

Comment: It's nice to see people taking an interest in numbers. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take it that the question is:

> Prove that $71\times 10^{7n+3}-17$ is divisible by $9\times 239$ for all values of $n\in \{ 0,1,2,3,\dots \}$.

We can use either modular arithmetic or proof by induction.

With proof by induction: the question evidences that it is true for $n=0$. Now suppose that it is true for some value $n=k$. Then, for $n=k+1$:

$$\begin{align} 71\times 10^{7(k+1)+3}-17&=71\times 10^{7k+7+3}-17\\ &=10^7\times 71\times 10^{7k+3}-17 \\ &=10^7\times (71\times 10^{7k+3}-17)+17\times10^7-17 \\ &= 10^7\times (71\times 10^{7k+3}-17)+17\times (10^7-1) \end{align}$$

Notice that the first bracketed term is a multiple of $9\times 239$ by the inductive hypothesis: this is precisely the claim that the case $n=k$ holds, which we assumed. As for the second bracketed term, $10^7-1=9999999=4649\times 9\times 239$.

So, the whole expression is a multiple of $9\times 239$, and the claim is true for $n=k+1$.

We've just proven that if it's true for some value $k$, then it's true for the value $k+1$. And also, it was true for $n=0$. So it's therefore true for $n=1$, and then for $n=2$, and then $n=3$, and so on.

This concludes the proof by induction method: for any value $k$, you can show that the statement is true by showing it is equivalent to showing the statement is true for $k-1,k-2,k-3,\dots,1,0$. And it's true for $0$.

If you want insight into *why* the statement is true, it is due to the fact that $10^7-1$ and $7887$ are multiples of $9\times 239$, as we saw. These insights may help you come up with similar patterns, or even to think about the repeated digit pattern you get as the result of calculating $\frac{71\times 10^{7n+3}-17}{9\times 239}$.

Answer (score 1):

${71\cdot 10^n-17}\over{9}$ is divisible by $239$ iff $71\cdot 10^n-17$ is divisible by $239$, that is iff $71\cdot 10^n \equiv 17 \mod 239 \iff 10^n \equiv 101*17\equiv 44 \mod 239$ .

This is true iff $\ \exists \ m \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ 10^n=239m+44$.

Let $(n_1,m_1),$ $(n_2,m_2)$ be two solutions to $10^n=239m+44$ and suppose $n_1<n_2$, then $10^{n_1}(10^{n_2-n_1}-1)=239(m_2-m_1)$, so we must have that $239\vert 10^{n_2-n_1}-1$.

This condition is not verified for $0<n_2-n_1<7$ but it is verified for $n_2-n_1=7$ so $239\vert 10^7-1$.

So in general $239\vert 10^a-1 \iff 239\vert 10^a-1-(10^7-1)=10^7(10^{a-7}-1)\iff 239\vert 10^{a-7}-1$ so, iterating this process, we see that our condotion depends only on the class of $n_2-n_1 \mod 7$, and by our previous observation we can say that the condition $239\vert 10^{n_2-n_1}-1$ is satisfyed iff $7\vert n_2-n_1$.

So it is necessary that $n$ is of the form $3+7k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand it's easy to see that, because $10^7\equiv 1 \mod 239$, if the congruence $10^n \equiv 44 \mod 239$ holds, then $10^{n+7} \equiv 44 \mod 239$, in other words so if $n$ works also $n+7$ works.

So finally we can conclude that $71\cdot 10^n-17 \over 9$ is divisible by $239$ iff $n=3+7k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$.